# postgresql and pgadming4 error on connecting to db server

Tags: postgresql

I have installed postgresql database and pgadmin4 on my fedora machine.
after starting the postgresql service and trying to connect to postgresql server
from pgadmin4
i am getting this error

```
Unable to connect to server:

FATAL: Ident authentication failed for user "postgres".
```

how should i fix this?

Comment: Check that you are using the right username and password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you create the "postgres" user while installing? You may be using wrong credentials, if you have forgotten the password, please change the `pg_hba.conf` (then reload or restart postgresql server) to allow all the connections from local without credentials, then change the password for `postgres` (again reload or restart postgresql) user. Change the `pg_hba.conf` to use credentials and try logging in.